# Let $G$ be a group and $A \subseteq G$. Assume $\{aA\mid a \in G\}$ form a partition of $G$. For some $a_0\in G$, $H=a_0A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an extra problem that my Algebra teacher suggested working through for practice.

Let $G$ be a group and let $A \subseteq  G$. Assume that $K = \{aA\mid a \in  G\} $ form a partition of G. Show that there exists $a_0\in G$ such that H = $a_0$A is a subgroup of G and $\{aA\mid a  \in  G\} = \{bH\mid b  \in  G\}$.

I know that if $K$ is a partition of $G$, then either $aA = bA$ or $aA  \cap  bA =  \emptyset $ for all $a,b \in G$ and that there must exist $a_0\in A$ such that for $x \in G$, $a_0a = x$ which is equivalent to $a_0 = xa^{-1}$, since $G$ is a group. This format is similar to $H =  a_0A$. I'm struggling with forming this subgroup $H$ and showing it's a subgroup. As for the second part, I think I could just show that each set is a subset of the other.

I am new to Abstract Algebra and struggle with the concepts. I am looking for very straightforward, simple suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: For any $a_0 \in G$, $a_0 G \subset G = eG = a_0 a_0^{-1} G \subset a_0 G$, so $a_0 G = G$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Any partition $P$ of $G$ defines an equivalence relation $\sim_P$ (and *vice versa*). Consider $$[e]_{\sim_K}=\{g\in G\mid g\sim_K e\},$$ where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

Note: $e$ is not necessarily in $A$.

Comment: Let me know if you need a further hint, @dorkichar.

Answer (score 1):

**Here’s the trick we want to use:**

> Let $g\in G$ be arbitrary. Then $g\in H$ if and only if $gH = H$ if and only if $gH \cap H \ne \emptyset$.

You should prove this! Use the fact that the translates of $H$ form a partition of $G$.

---

Now, the first step in proving $H$ is a subgroup is showing that for any $h\in H$, its inverse $h^{-1}$ is also in $H$. Explain why $e\in h^{-1}H$, and why this proves that $h^{-1}\in H$.

The second step in proving $H$ is a subgroup is showing that for any $g,h\in H$, their product $gh$ is also in $H$. Using the step above, prove that $g\in (gh)H$ and explain why this means that $gh\in H$.